# No asset_path in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, actionmailer

Whenever I try to send an email, I can't seem to be able to use asset_path within image_tag in order to load an image. The `src` attribute of the image tag is set to an empty string. I can't find any record in the documentation of asset_path being disabled in ActionMailer, so I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you not just use the standard `src` attribute that `image_tag` gives you?

Comment: You should use the _url helpers not the _path helpers anyway, since the email will need to resolve the complete URL of the image.

Comment: @pdobb The problem is not with the `image_tag` itself, it's just that asset_path is resolving to `""` when I check the html of the email.

Comment: @Jon I tried to use `asset_url` and it too resolved to an empty string.

Comment: Have you tried just using `image_url` rather than `asset_url`?

Comment: @Jon image_path and image_url, and asset_path and asset_url.

Answer (score 0):

The `image_tag` will auto expand your images so you don't need to combine the two.  So instead of `<%= image_tag(asset_path "smile.png") %>` you can use `<%= image_tag "smile.png" %>` and it should expand it correctly. Also if this is an email you need to use a url instead of a path otherwise the image won't render (emails cannot handle relative urls) this was already mentioned by jon.

What version of Rails and ruby are you using? You can debug in the console

```
$ rails c
> puts helper.image_tag "smile.png" 
> puts helper.image_tag(asset_path "smile.png")
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of debugging at the console. But, to make it work, I needed to fully qualify helper, i.e. ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag